# Calling grouped dataframe by its columns name in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I asked previously the wrong question.

I have dataframe called df

it looks like this.

```
filename result
101        A
101        C
101        D
112        B
112        C
153        A
153        D
```

I have added this code to make in array format

```
results_df=df.groupby('filename')["result"].agg(list)
```

now results_df looks like this

```
101  [A,C,D]
112  [B,C]
153  [A,D]
```

But when I try to call each column separetly it does not work

I call filename using `results_df["filename"]` i get error ***KeyError: 'filename'***

I call result using `results_df["result"]` i get error ***KeyError: 'result'***

I tried renaming the dataframe but does not work

```
results_df.renamecolumns = ["filename","result" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
results_df = df.groupby('filename')["result"].agg(list).reset_index()
```

Now you should be able to call, `results_df["filename"]` and `results_df["result"]`.